# Mixed conditional sentence with type 1

Tags: conditionals

Assumming that tommorrow my friend will take a examination, but he didn't study anything, so it's too late for him now, he is doomed for sure :). Is it grammatically correct if I say to my friend:

> If you want to pass the test, you should have studied harder (in the past).

I did some research about mixed conditionals, but almost all the documents/blogs said that the if clause must be unreal conditionals. The verb "want" in my sentence is confusing me, I don't even know if it's likely (possible) situation or unreal (hypothetical) situation.

I know it is correct to say: *If you want to pass the test, you should study harder*. But in this sentence, I feel like he still has time to study.

Comment: No. 'If you wanted to pass the test, you should have studied harder.' or (if a retake is possible) 'If you want to pass the test, you need to study harder.'

Comment: Since, in the speaker's mind, there is no chance that the friend will pass the test, the sentence calls for the irrealis, not the real.

Comment: I don't understand why this question would be closed as "off topic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's grammatically correct to have a present tense conditional before a past tense statement, for example:

> If you are hungry, you should have packed some food.

However in the example you give there's a semantic problem. Since the opportunity to pass the test has passed, what the person wants now if of no consequence, what matters is what they wanted at the time they had an opportunity to affect the outcome. So it would be semantically correct to say

> If you wanted to pass the test, you should have studied harder.

(use past tense "wanted" instead of present tense "want").

After the time that the test is done, another semantic option becomes available, and we can talk of what the person wants now in regards to the result of having passed or not passed the test, by using the perfect aspect on test passing:

> if you want to have passed, it's too late, you should have studied harder.

but this option is not available in the time between passing being an option and the passing/failing actually happening. In this particular window, English semantics doesn't really allow us to speak of what the person wants in the present regarding the test outcome as a conditional statement. Strange that!

Comment: The OP is talking about a test taking place in the future.

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica yes, I am aware of that. Is there something in my post that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Since the opportunity to pass the test has passed

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica The OP says "he didn't study anything, so it's too late for him now, he is doomed for sure". Even though the test is in the future, the opportunity for passing it is in the past - it's too late now. I'm suggesting this condition affects the sentence structure available - you say "wanted to pass" instead of "want to pass"